# same aliases and functions for user and root in fish shell

Tags: fish

How can I make aliases defined in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` and functions defined in `~/.config/fish/functions` available for the root user as well?

symlinking to `/root/.config/fish` didn't do the job. Furthermore, I'd also like to be able to use my functions and aliases via `sudo`, which is currently not working as well.

How do you guys do that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a solution for the first problem (I don't have any functions that are useful for the root user), but the second one (functions not working as an argument for `sudo`) can be solved with a wrapper function:

```
function sudo
    if functions -q $argv[1]
        set argv fish -c "$argv"
    end
    command sudo $argv
end
```

The issue is of course that `sudo` is an external command (usually at /usr/bin/sudo) that cannot know about fish internals like function definitions. So this wrapper will call fish if you give it a function name. Of course, since this launches a new fish session, some things, like `cd` will not be useful because it won't alter the state of the main fish session.

Comment: cool, thank you. works and makes sense. i think it's a useful thing.

Comment: While I like this function, it is dangerous that it won't deal with arguments containing spaces. For example: `ls` in fish is a also function. If I run `sudo ls "My File"`, it will look for files named `My` and `File` separately.

Answer (score 2):

I use a symlink to my config.fish and works perfectly. Have you checked the permissions?

```
777 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Dez 21  2015 /root/.config/fish/config.fish -> /home/lara/.config/fish/config.fish
```

In newer versions you can also use the directory /etc/fish/ for system-wide configuration

The problem with sudo I solved with an alias:

```
# -E just preserv env. It's not really
# necessary, but may be useful.
function sudo; command sudo -sE $argv; end
```

from sudo man page:

> -s, --shell
>     Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's
>   password database entry.  If a command is specified, it is passed to
>   the shell for execution via
>                    the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Old question that I came across while attempting to do the same thing myself.

Neither existing solution from @faho or @LaraMaia solves the first part of the question, which is really what I needed for my use-case.  Both solutions only handled functions that are defined in `~/.config/fish/functions`.  In-memory functions and aliases that have not been "saved" do not work.

So here's a version that does work for aliases/in-memory functions:

```
function sudo
    if functions -q -- "$argv[1]"
        set cmdline (
            for arg in $argv
                printf "\"%s\" " $arg
            end
        )
        set -x function_src (string join "\n" (string escape --style=var (functions "$argv[1]")))
        set argv fish -c 'string unescape --style=var (string split "\n" $function_src) | source; '$cmdline
        command sudo -E $argv
    else
        command sudo $argv
    end
end
```

Commented and slightly expanded version at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/NotTheDr01ds/6357e48b511735c42b94c4cc081ac5dc).